# Event Reciever firing twice sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, event-receivers

Hi I have a event receiver(item adding,item editing,item added), it was working fine before ...now it has started to fire twice...any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case it was accidentally doubled registration of event reciever. Check it with SharePoint Manager 2010 for example.

Comment: Hi Alex, could u tell me how can i check if the event receiver has been double registered in the sharepoint manager?

Comment: Download SharePoint Manager 2010 (http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/51438/download/146573) (note! you need first release, NOT v2 alfa!), and check as at this my screenshot: http://gyazo.com/15c4b2c58844d0e61c62da1a1fc2884d.png. Note the event receivers node.

Comment: Thanks Alex! That was it!... there were multiple registration, i used the sharepoint manager...Thanks guys for possible answers..

Answer (score 4):

Before you call update on the item in your receiver, are you calling `this.DisableEventFiring()` and then `this.EnableEventFiring()` straight after?

Comment: Hi James, i am not calling any of those?...do u have to mention them?

Comment: If you are updating your item within your event receiver you would want to use these because otherwise the Update call will trigger another Updating/Updated event to fire.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article on the subject from Simple-Talk - [Managing ItemUpdating and ItemUpdated Events Firing Twice in a SharePoint Item Event Receiver](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/managing-itemupdating-and-itemupdated-events-firing-twice-in-a-sharepoint-item-event-receiver/). Well worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem this week when I wanted to publish a page directly from the "Publish" ribbon button.

My event receiver fired three times in a row. The first time for the check in, The second time for the publication, and the last time to approve it.

What I dit was checking the afterproperties, to see if I will get the correct values. I did not find another solution.

If you are updating your item in the event receiver, than you could try James Love his solution.